How to get all the templates by Solr in sitecore
Can I get this by Solr C#? I need assistance to Get a list of all Sitecore templates, including

Template Name
Number of pages using this template
URL of page using the template


What code have you tried so far?

@MarcelGruber I have no idea where to begin. I have only solr url

In which case, this question needs a bit more focus. There are a number of ways to do this in C#. Sitecore Content Search API, SolrNet, or you can even manually construct a URL containing the query, make the web request(s) and then parse the results with C# / Newtonsoft Json.NET. You can also do this with Sitecore PowerShell Extensions (though that approach doesn't involve C#).

@MarcelGruber  Anything fine content search api, solrnet or etc. I tried with Powershell its taking to much of time.

@Hasanshali I have uploaded the answer below that uses Content Search API to fetch the required details. Let me know in case you have any queries.

Using Content Search API, something like the below should do the job:
List<SearchResultItem> searchResults = null;

var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web_index");
var startItem = Sitecore.Context.Site.StartItem();

using (var context = index.CreateSearchContext())
{

    var query = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>();
    query = query.Where(x => x.Paths.Contains(startItem.ID));
    query = query.Where(x => x.DatabaseName == startItem.Database.Name);

    searchResults = query.GetResults().Select(x => x.Document).ToList();
}
Dictionary<string, int> templates = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach (var item in searchResults)
{
    if (!templates.ContainsKey(item.TemplateName))
    {
        templates.Add(item.TemplateName, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        templates[item.TemplateName]++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Item with {item.ItemId} has a template of {item.TemplateName} and a URL of {Sitecore.Context.Site.HostName}/{item.Path.Replace(startItem.Paths.Path,"")}.");
}
foreach (var template in templates)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"There are {template.Value} items using the {template.Key} template.");
}

Note: I have not tested this, so may need a bit of tweaking. Also, you may need to add some additional where clauses to refine your query.

You can use below code snippet to get the details on the templates along with the item count and item urls, with the help of Content Search API using Solr.
using Sitecore.ContentSearch;
using Sitecore.ContentSearch.SearchTypes;
using Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrNetIntegration;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Links;
using SolrNet.Commands.Parameters;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web_index").CreateSearchContext())
{
  var site = Sitecore.Context.Site;
  var language = Sitecore.Context.Language.Name;
  Item startItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(site.StartPath);
  string startPathID = startItem.ID.Guid.ToString("N");
  string query = $"_path:{startPathID} AND _language:{language}";

  var queryOptions = new QueryOptions
  {
     Grouping = new GroupingParameters
     {
        Fields = new[] { "_templatename" },
        Limit = -1
     }
  };

  var result = context.Query<SearchResultItem>(query, queryOptions);
  var outResult = new List<Tuple<string, int, List<string>>>();
  foreach (var group in result.Grouping)
  {
    foreach (var grp in group.Value.Groups)
    {
       var templateName = grp.GroupValue;
       var itemCount = grp.NumFound;
       List<string> itemUrls = new List<string>();
       foreach (var templateItem in grp.Documents)
       {
          var item = templateItem.GetItem();
          if (item != null)
          {
            string itemUrl = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item);
            itemUrls.Add(itemUrl);
          }
          else
          {
            itemUrls.Add(templateItem.Path);
          }
        }
        outResult.Add(Tuple.Create(templateName, itemCount, itemUrls));
      }
    }
    foreach (var templateDetail in outResult)
    {
      Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info($"Template Name {templateDetail.Item1}", this);
      Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info($"Item Count {templateDetail.Item2}", this);
      Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info($"Item Urls {string.Join(",", templateDetail.Item3)}", this);
    }
}

In the above search query, _path is set to the context site startpath. You can change this path according to your use case. Thereafter all the items retrieved from Solr are grouped by _templatename parameter, in order to fetch the content items from Solr grouped by template name.
Below is the Solr query sent through above code snippet.
?q=_path:f382240db5794d3f94ce73272ad3bce1 AND _language:en&fq=_indexname:(sitecore_web_index)&group=true&group.field=_templatename&group.limit=-1&group.format=grouped

Using above way, you will be successfully fetch the details on the templates along with the item urls and item count assocaited with the template.
Hope this helps!! Let me know in case you have any queries.
